# Gerar números aleatórios a partir de um conjunto pré-definido

Tags: c, random

Como gerar um numero aleatório em um intervalo de números não sequenciais. Por exemplo, uma função que escolha aleatoriamente entre os valores, 3, 10,  20 e 2334 na linguagem C

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    srand(time(0)); // escolhe sequencia de numeros aleatorios
    int valores[] = {3, 10, 20, 2334};
    int n = sizeof valores / sizeof *valores;

    printf("%d\n", valores[rand() % n]); // possible bias

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Podes usar a função Rand() e a função SRand(), a última serve para alimentar o Random, para que em cada compilação não mostre o mesmo valor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    int gera()
    {
        srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
        int val[] = { 3, 10, 20, 2334 };//Valores
        int num = sizeof valores / sizeof * val;

        return(valores[rand() % num]); 
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("%d",gera());
    getch();
    }
```