# Geração de aleatórios

Tags: c, números-aleatórios

Olá. Me surgiu uma dúvida em um estudo números aleatório em C. Como eu faria pra gerar um valor em um intervalo que não seja continuo? Gerar um valor entre 10 a 15 ou de 20 a 25, por exemplo.

Comment: Veja se essa pergunta lhe ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69332/gerar-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-a-partir-de-um-conjunto-pr%c3%a9-definido ou essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210172/gerar-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-em-c

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, você soma o tamanho dos intervalos e depois espalha o número nos intervalos dados.

Por exemplo, o intervalo de 10 a 15 tem 6 números (contando com o 10 e o 15) e o de 20 a 25 tem mais seis números. Assim, você tem um total de 12 números para escolher. Então você sorteia um número de 0 a 11 e se for entre 0 e 5, você soma 10, produzindo um número de 10 a 15. Se for entre 6 e 11, você soma 14, produzindo um número de 20 a 25.

Por exemplo:

```
#include <time.h>

int numero_10a15_e_20a25() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x = rand() % 12;
    return x + (x < 6 ? 10 : 14);
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", numero_10a15_e_20a25());
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/dMInTQ)

Outra forma de fazer é usando um array para mapear o valor de 0 até a quantidade de elementos menos 1 para um conjunto de números quaisquer. Por exemplo:

```
#include <time.h>

#define TAMANHO_DO_ARRAY(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int numero_faixa(int *faixa, int quantidade) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    return faixa[rand() % quantidade];
}

int numero_10a15_e_20a25() {
    int faixas[] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
    return numero_faixa(faixas, TAMANHO_DO_ARRAY(faixas));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d", numero_10a15_e_20a25());
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/7x0jO9)

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu não tinha sacado que tu pode resolver isso dando essa "tratada" nos valores da geração. Que massa. Valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Já pensou em fazer esse procedimento em cadeia?

Não manjo em C, portanto nem vou me arriscar, porém, vou tentar passar a lógica envolvida, ai é só você passar pra linguagem C e usar o rand...

```
var = numero-aleatorio (1 a 3);

Se (var == 1){
  num = numero-aleatorio (10 a 15);
}

Se (var == 2){
  num = numero-aleatorio (20 a 25);
}

Se (var == 3){
  num = numero-aleatorio (30 a 35);
}

Mostre(num);
```

Para complementar, resolvi fazer o exemplo prático:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Funçao para gerar os numeros aleatórios
int numeroAleatorio(){
    // Inicializa o gerador de números aleatórios
    srand(time(NULL));

    // Faz o primeiro sorteio, para saber opção de numero vai usar
    int p = rand() % 3;

    // Se for a opção 1
    if(p == 0)
        // Retorne de 10 a 15
        return 10 + (rand() % 5);
    // Se for a opção 2
    if(p == 1)
        // Retorne de 20 a 25
        return 20 + (rand() % 5);
    // Se for a opção 3
    if(p == 2)
        // Retorne de 30 a 35
        return 30 + (rand() % 5);
}

int main(void) {
    // Chama a funçao numero aleatório e a imprime na tela
    printf("Numero Sorteado: %d", numeroAleatorio());
}
```

[Exemplo ideone](https://ideone.com/QTY8LU)

[Fonte Pesquisada 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39215/faixa-de-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-em-c)

[Fonte Pesquisada 2](http://linguagemc.com.br/valores-aleatorios-em-c-com-a-funcao-rand/)

Comment: Queria só agradecer ao Victor Stafusa, não conhecia o ideone, graças a essa ferramenta que eu consegui fazer o exemplo pratico. Vlw! Comentei aqui porque infelizmente não posso comentar na sua resposta.